# while submitting large files using jquery ajax all input fields get empty on server site php

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, file-upload

I am trying to send large files to server using jquery ajax and formData. 
The data is received if i send 7 files with 1 mb each, but if i try to send 10 files at a time than the input field received on server site is empty, though input are send properly to server. following is my code for file upload.

```
//php code
public function multipleupload()
    {
        $title = $_POST["title"];
        $property_id = $_POST["propertyId"];
        $userId = $_POST["userId"];
        $albumId = $_POST["albumId"];
        $profileId = $_POST["profile_id"];

        if($albumId == "") {
            $album = new Album;
            $album->title = $title; 
            $album->property_id = $property_id;
            $album->user_id = $userId;
            $album->profile_id = $profileId;
            $album->save();

            $albumID = $album->id;
            $userId = $album->user_id;
            $folder = str_replace(" ","-",$title. '-' . date("Y-m-d_His"));
            if(!is_dir('uploads/album/'. $folder) || (!is_dir('uploads/album/'. $folder . "/original") && !is_dir('uploads/album/'. $folder . "/thumb"))) {
                mkdir('uploads/album/'. $folder);
                mkdir('uploads/album/'. $folder. "/original");
                mkdir('uploads/album/'. $folder. "/thumb");
            }
        }
        else {
            $album = DB::table("photo_album")->select('*')->where('album_id', '=', $albumId)->orderBy('id','DESC')->first();
            $folder = $album->file_path;

            $album = Album::findOrFail($albumId);
            $album->update(['title' => $title]);

            $albumID = $album->id;
        }
        $fileCount = count($_FILES["finalFiles"]['name']);
        $photos = array();
        for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
        if($_POST["rmImage"] == "" || !in_array($i,explode(",",$_POST["rmImage"]))) {
        $ImgFile = str_replace(" ","-",pathinfo($_FILES["finalFiles"]['name'][$i], PATHINFO_FILENAME))."-".date("Y-m-d_His").".".pathinfo($_FILES["finalFiles"]['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);    
        $target_original_path = 'uploads/album/'. $folder . '/original/' . $ImgFile;
        $target_thumb_path = 'uploads/album/'. $folder . '/thumb/' . $ImgFile;
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['finalFiles']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_original_path))
        {
            $imagine = new Imagine\Gd\Imagine();

            $mode    = Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET;

            $thumb_size    = new Imagine\Image\Box(100, 100);

            $imagine->open($target_original_path)
                ->thumbnail($thumb_size, $mode)
                ->save($target_thumb_path);

            $size    = new Imagine\Image\Box(650, 350);

            $imagine->open($target_original_path)
                ->thumbnail($size, $mode)
                ->save($target_original_path);

                $filename = $_FILES["finalFiles"]["name"][$i];
                //$album = Album::where('user_id','=',$userId)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();
                $photo_details = ['album_id' => $albumID, 
                                  'property_id' => $property_id, 
                                  'file_name' => $filename, 
                                  'created_by' => $userId, 
                                  'updated_by' => $userId, 
                                  'url' => URL::to('/').'/'.$target_original_path, 
                                  'thumb_url' => URL::to('/').'/'.$target_thumb_path, 
                                  'file_path' => $folder];
                array_push($photos, $photo_details);
        }
        else
        {
            echo '{"status":"Failure","response":[],"message":"Failed to upload property image."}';
            $status = "failure";
         }
        }   
      }

      if(count($photos) > 0) {
         $albumPhoto = PhotoAlbum::insert($photos);
      }
}  

//Jquery Code
$("#photoAlbum").click(function() {
      if($("#title").val() == '') {
       $(".error-title").show();
       $(".error-photo").hide();
      }
      else {
        if($("#preview-area ul li").size() == 0) {
            $(".error-title").hide();
            $(".error-photo").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#photoAlbum").attr("disabled", true);
            var form = $('form')[0]; // You need to use standart javascript object here
            var formData = new FormData(form);
            $.ajax({
              url: "api/multipleupload",
              type: "POST",
              data: formData,
              cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false, 
              success: function(result){
                $state.go('albums',{propertyID:  $scope.propertyId});
                toastr.success('Album Has been Added successfully.');
              }
            });
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Check PHP ini settings for `max_upload_size` for start.

Comment: Check this [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736358/how-to-upload-large-size-image-by-intervention-image-in-laravel-5/45736689?noredirect=1#comment78432381_45736689), might the same issue you are facing.

Comment: I have increased the max_upload_size  = 200M and max_file_uploads = 100 than also i am not reiceving any data and i am getting error from server undefined index title at line number 1 in php code

Comment: So your actual problem now resolved. For *undefined index title at line number 1*, post OR check your master blade file code for title index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I have experienced issues uploading files using Jquery ajax and FormData with some weird outputs in the server side ([my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45503814/laravel-5-4-not-able-to-parse-formdata-javascript-object-sent-using-jquery-ajax)).

What solved my problem was avoiding jquery and take a more *vanilla approach* using `XMLHttpRequest()` like so:

```
function save(action){
    var formElement = document.getElementById("form");
    var formData = new FormData(formElement);
    formData.append('_token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "{{url('myUrl')}}");
    request.send(formData);

    request.onload = function(oEvent) {
      if (request.status == 200) {
        toastr.success('Yai! Saved successfully!');
      } else {
        toastr.error('Oh oh! Something went really wrong!');
      }
      $( "#form-wrapper" ).toggleClass( "be-loading-active" );
    };
}
```

And in my controller I could just access files normally in the request object:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->nameOfInput);
}
```

Also, as people suggested in the comments, if you are handling large files make sure your php parameters are configured accordingly in your `php.ini`.

Hope this helps you.